# What happens if your US visa, B1/B2 expires (unused visa) without travelling

Tags: angola

What happens if your US visa expires without travelling?
Indeed, I have already travelled to the United States before. But with another visa (this unused B1/B2), some family restrictions, my wife's death, prevented me from travelling during the two years of validity of my visa. Would it be a problem to get another visa now?

Answer (score 10):

Nothing happens. If anything, it helps build the perception that you don't have immigrant intent.

An unused non immigrant visa does not cause any future immigration issues. If asked for a reason in the next interview, it is perfectly alright to mention the reasons you have listed here.

I'm sorry for your loss.